# How does one develop a Lev Tov

Tags: how-to, mussar-ethics, pirke-avot-ethicsof

In Pirkei Avot 2:9 it's Rabbi Elazar Ben Arach who states that a Lev Tov (good heart) is the greatest good - the best "acquisition" - or best trait for a person to acquire, or which should be the goal or aim of a person in this life. More literally, "unto which good way should a person cleave?" it's a Lev Tov. (Based on the question of Rabban Yochanan Ben Zakai: איזוהי דרך ישרה שידבק בה האדם).

So the straight path,or walking a/the right path, consists of having a Lev Tov.

My question is: How does one develop a Lev Tov?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/8144/603

Comment: As R' Zundel Salanter said to the young Yisrael Lipkin, words R Yisrael Salanter said struck his heart like lightning: Yisrael, learn Mussar, so that you can be a yarei Shamayim. Mussar has a whole set of tools... I think I have FAR more to say on this topic than I would fit in an answer.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VtGC.jpg same thing http://www.sefaria.org/Rabbeinu_Bahya,_Shemot.13.17

Answer (score 2):

[Rabbi Menashe Ben Porat - on hidabroot.org](http://www.hidabroot.org/question/34717) says that a Lev Tov is a heart free of hatred, jealousy, anger, etc,. and full of love and interest that other's should have it good.

He recommends the following to acquire a Lev Tov.

1 - Learn Mussar and absorb it.

2 - Do Chesed, speak in a low and calm tone even when angry.

Comment: Read "Let There Be Rain" - A lesson a day on making Gratitude a part of our lives - by Rabbi Shimon Finkelman and Rabbi Zechariah Wallerstein.